# Inheritance vs Object Creation in Java

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

Why do we use Inheritance, when we can just create objects of the other class and use it's methods and instance variables? (Also vice versa- why do we create objects of the other class when we can just use inheritance?)

This is not a homework question. I asked this question to my teacher when he was teaching us Inheritance and he didn't know the answer. I asked my tuition teacher and even he couldn't help me. I read the textbook multiple times, searched the internet for a simple explanation, but had no luck. Please help me.

Comment: This is not a programming learning page!

Comment: I don't understand... I am just a newbie. Please elaborate and help.  Please explain me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: This is a very broad question. You're basically asking someone to explain inheritance. Try reading [the wikipedia article on inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)) to get you started.

Comment: Thanks a lot @khelwood. It's just that they always avoid us when we ask such questions in school and I couldn't find anything in the internet.

Answer (score 4):

Inheritance and composition both can be used alternatively in for code reuse-ability.

**Why composition is preferred over inheritance?**
It is preferable to use composition rather then inheritance as it serves the purpose of code reuse-ability without having the need to worry about the trickle down effect of change. Thus it provides more loosely coupling where we do not have to worry about changing some code causing some other dependent code requiring change.

**For Example:**
Consider we have the following classes:

```
    class Person
    {
        public String name;
        public int age;

        public Person(String name,int age)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }
    }


    class Student : Person
    {
        public String rollNumber;
        public double cgpa;


        public Student(String rollNumber,double cgpa,String name,int age):base(name,age)
        {
            this.rollNumber = rollNumber;
            this.cgpa = cgpa;
        }
    }

    //and the main which call these as
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Student student = new Student("Roll1234", 3.5, "John Doe", 32);
    }
```

Now what if the Person class was to change and be like following:

```
class Person
{
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public int age;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

This change cannot be achieved without changing all the classes that inherit from the Person class, in our class which is the Student class.

Now consider another case in which we have used composition as in our following code:

```
class Person
{
    public String name;
    public int age;

    public Person(String name,int age)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

class Student 
{
    public String rollNumber;
    public double cgpa;

    public Person person;

    public Student(String rollNumber,double cgpa,Person person)
    {
        this.rollNumber = rollNumber;
        this.cgpa = cgpa;
        this.person = person;
    }
}

//and the main
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Person person = new Person("John Doe", 32);
    Student student = new Student("Roll1234", 3.5, person);
}
```

Now in this case if we are to make the change in Person class as follows:

```
class Person
{
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public int age;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

We do not require to change the Student class at all. Thus composition makes our design much more flexible when it comes to change.

However the rule of thumb stands, if there is an "is a" relation go for inheritance and go for composition for "has a" relation.

Yet keep in mind if you want to achieve code reuse composition will always be a better choice.